# Mathematical Derivation of Residual Risk

Tags: risk, capm

I understand the [difference between Excess, Residual and Active Returns](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/25619/excess-residual-and-active-return).

I also understand what **Active Risk**; defined as: $\sigma_{r_P-r_B}$  (i.e. standard deviation of the difference in returns between our portfolio and benchmark).

Now, what exactly is **Residual Risk**? I often see it defined (e.g. [here](http://people.brandeis.edu/~yanzp/Study%20Notes/Active%20Portfolio%20Management.pdf)) as:

$\omega_p = \sqrt{\sigma^ 2_p-\beta^2_p\sigma^2_B}$

with $\beta_P = \frac{\text{Cov}(r_p, r_B)}{Var(r_B)}$

Where does this derivation come from? What is residual risk exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $\beta$ is the coefficient of the portfolio regressed on the benchmark. That is
\begin{align*}
r_P = \alpha+\beta r_B + \varepsilon,
\end{align*}
where $\varepsilon$ is the residual. The standard deviation of the residual is called the residual risk. Specifically,
\begin{align*}
std(\varepsilon) &= \sqrt{var(r_P-\beta r_B-\alpha)}\\
&=\sqrt{\sigma_P^2 + \beta^2 \sigma_B^2 - 2 \beta \rho(r_P, r_B) \sigma_P\sigma_B}\\
&=\sqrt{\sigma_P^2 + \beta^2 \sigma_B^2 - 2 \beta\, \beta\, var(r_B)}\\
&= \sqrt{\sigma_P^2 - \beta^2 \sigma_B^2},
\end{align*}
since $cov(r_P, r_B) = \rho(r_P, r_B)\sigma_P \sigma_B =\beta\, var(r_B)$.